# How do I search a file, count the number of hits and write the number to column B in a .csv?

Tags: python, search, csv, count

Here is my script. It currently finds all the files in *path* which contain * *cycle* * *.log* and then finds all the lines in those files that contain "timeout of" and pasts them into outfilecamera as well as the name of the file that it found it in.

```
i = 0

ii = "\n"

for i in range(0,listlength):
    path = pathlist[i].strip()
    outfilecamera = join((path), 'cameratimeouts.txt')   
    os.chdir(path)
    for path in glob.glob("*cycle*.log"):
        with open(path) as f_in, open(outfilecamera, 'a') as f_out:
            f_out.writelines(path)
            f_out.writelines(ii)
            f_out.writelines(line for line in f_in if "timeout of" in line)
```

What I want to do as well is COUNT the number of times the hit is found in the file and paste the number into column B in a csv file. I.e. each row would be the number of hits in each file. Column A would ideally equal *i*.

I have been searching how for ages and cannot find a count function!?

I appreciate all our help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of times its found is hidden here:

```
f_out.writelines(line for line in f_in if "timeout of" in line)
```

So, all you have to do is consume the generator first, say into a list:

```
matched_lines = list(line for line in f_in if "timeout of" in line)
f_out.writelines(matched_lines)
```

Next, simply collect the number of matches for each file. Create blank list at the top of your loop, and then inside your loop, add the file name and the count to it:

```
file_counts = []

# .. your loop starts

    matched_lines = list(line for line in f_in if "timeout of" in line)
    f_out.writelines(matched_lines)
    file_counts.append((os.path.basename(path),len(matched_lines)))
```

Once you are done processing the files:

```
with open('results.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(['File Name','Count'])
    writer.writerows(file_counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what You need...

```
import csv
import glob

searched = 'timeout of'
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    cwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    cwriter.writerow(['File', 'Number'])
    for path in glob.glob("*cycle*.log"):
        with open(path) as f_in:
            n = 0
            for line in f_in.readlines():
                if searched in line:
                    n += 1
            cwriter.writerow([path, n])
```

Answer (score 0):

What about grep? This task would be extremely easy with it.

```
grep -c 'timeout of' *cycle*.log
```

For csv like output, you need to replace the colon to comma:

```
grep -c 'timeout of' *cycle*.log | sed 's/:/,/'
```

And put the result into the cameratimeouts.txt file:

```
grep -c 'timeout of' *cycle*.log | sed 's/:/,/' >cameratimeouts.txt
```

If you would stick with python, my solution would be:

```
for i in range(0,listlength):
    path = pathlist[i].strip()
    outfilecamera = join((path), 'cameratimeouts.txt')   
    os.chdir(path)
    for path in glob.glob("*cycle*.log"):
        with open(path) as f_in, open(outfilecamera, 'a') as f_out:
            f_out.write('%s,%d\n' % (path, sum(l.count('timeout of') for l in f_in)))
```